# What justifies the use of “il” in “les yeux d'Andrée, qu'il faisait pointus” ?

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif, pronoms-personnels, littérature

Can someone explain or at least justify the use of the pronoun "il" in the following sentence?

> Avant que j’eusse terminé ma phrase, je vis dans les yeux d’Andrée,
>   ***qu’il faisait pointus*** comme ces pierres qu’à cause de cela les joailliers ont de la peine à employer, passer un regard préoccupé,
>   comme ces têtes de privilégiés qui soulèvent un coin du rideau avant
>   qu’une pièce soit commencée et qui se sauvent aussitôt pour ne pas
>   être aperçus. **[1]**

I really can't help but think it'd be legitimate to write "***qu'elle*** faisait pointus […]" instead.

**[1]** M. Proust, *A la recherche du temps perdu*, Tome VII – Albertine disparue.

Comment: Haha... As a native french, I can't understand this sentence neither :D. The use of « j'eusse » says it is old french. It seems to be a complex writting which requires to read multiple times the same line to understand it...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm a (native swiss-)french speaker as well. Frankly, I re-readed it many times… Yet I wonder: could it be a mere mistake, simple as that? Is there any reasonable justification for that third person masculine?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, pas de virgule après _ces pierres_ parce que la subordonnée _qu'à cause de cela..._ est déterminative et pas qualificative (il y a le même genre de nuance en anglais avec l'utilisation de _that_ et _which_)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi L'erreur n'est pas à exclure. Cet extrait est tiré de l'avant dernier tome de *À la recherche...* publié 3 ans après la mort de Proust. Le travail d'édition orignal a été fait à partir de deux manuscrits d'époques différentes.  L'édition de La Pléïade signale pour ce tome de nombreuses additions et corrections dans les manuscrits autographes. Il faudrait pouvoir comparer diverses éditions et savoir de quand date la citation de l'OP, sachant que l’original de la dactylographie, que Proust était en train de retravailler au moment de sa mort, n'a été retrouvée qu'en 1986.

Comment: @Laure Sur le site on a de la difficulté à consulter un dictionnaire. Alors je pense que je vais plutôt continuer de penser qu'il s'agit d'un éclair de génie de l'auteur et je présume de votre propos qu'à La Pléïade on a une citation conforme à l'extrait. Si on fait une recherche du niveau de celle que vous proposez, je la récompenserai. Merci.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je pense que le mot "il" se réfère au "regard préoccupé" qui "faisait pointus" les yeux d'Andrée. Le regard que le narrateur voit passer dans les yeux d'Andrée donne à ses yeux une apparence pointue. La phrase est tournée à l'envers pour donner un effet de style, j'imagine. Si on la tourne dans l'autre sens ça donne :

> [...] je vis passer un regard préoccupé dans les yeux d'Andrée qu’il faisait pointus comme ces pierres [...]

C'est sans doute moins joli (voire grammaticalement incorrect, j'ai juste coupé et collé des mots pour réorganiser la phrase) mais on voit bien que c'est "le regard" qui "faisait pointus" les yeux d'Andrée. (Et c'est de toute manière le seul mot au masculin singulier de la phrase ; je n'ai pas l'impression que ça se réfère à quelque chose de la phrase précédente.)

---

The pronoun "il" refers to Andrée's "regard préoccupé"; it is this "regard préoccupé" which makes Andrée's eyes look "pointus". I believe the sentence was written in this way for a stylistic effect, but if you write it in the opposite way, you get:

> [...] je vis passer un regard préoccupé dans les yeux d'Andrée qu’il faisait pointus comme ces pierres [...]

and then I think it's clearer that the "il" refers to the "regard". (Besides, "regard" is the only word using the singular masculine in the sentence, and reading the context I don't think the "il" refers to something from the previous sentence.)

Comment: It feels a bit weird to write an explanation about a French text in English, but since the question was asked in English...

Comment: La phrase retournée serait plutôt : « [...] je vis passer un regard préoccupé dans  les yeux d'Andrée qui les faisait pointus comme ces pierres [...] »

Comment: @Toto, ta version fait de Andrée l’antécédent de _qui_ et donc le sujet de _faisait_.  Si je devais réorganiser la phrase en changeant l'endroit où la subordonnée apparaît, ce serait _je vis passer dans les yeux d'Andrée un regard préoccupé qui les faisait pointus..._

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Effectivement, ça semble plus juste.

Comment: Merci à tous ceux qui ont répondu. @Najib Idrissi : Ta réponse me semble excellente ; cette longue phrase m'est devenue parfaitement compréhensible grâce à toi. Chapeau et merci !

Comment: @Torquemada Pas de quoi. Si tu veux, tu peux ["accepter"](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) la réponse en cliquant sur le bouton vert en-dessous des boutons de vote à gauche de la question (et si par la suite tu reçois une meilleure réponse tu pourras toujours changer d'avis, ou décider de ne plus accepter ma réponse).

Comment: @Najib Idrissi : il s'agit de ma première contribution-question sur ce site, je découvre seulement ses fonctionnalités :-) J'ai déjà voté pour ta réponse, mais j'ignore si c'est de cela dont tu parles... (Remarque: je consulte actuellement la version "appli" du forum)

Comment: @Torquemada Non, il s'agit d'un bouton qui a cette forme : ✓ (je ne sais pas si c'est utilisable en mode mobile).

Comment: @Najib Idrissi : C'est fait !

Comment: C'est pas parce que Andrée louchait (un peu), disons par curiosité (et non pas parce qu'il était  préoccupé)?

Answer (score 2):

*Il* ne renvoie pas à Andrée, mais à l'*état* des yeux d'Andrée, comme s'il y avait des *pointes* (des clous fins et piquants, et non deux pieux affûtés) dans son regard.

***Pointus*** : tapissé de pointes, comme le tapis d'un yogi de bandes dessinées.

Le `s` de *pointu**s*** accorde *pointu* à yeux, s'il s'agit d'une erreur typographique, c'est à l'état.

En aucun cas *pointu**e*** n'est possible, car cela imposerait le *elle* qui renvoie à Andrée.

De nos jours on dirait *... qui étaient pointus*, pour parler de l'expression des yeux d'un regard inquisiteur, en recherche ou inquiet.

Mais *Andrée* n'a pas naturellement les yeux pointus, elle vient seulement de les rendre ainsi sous une émotions récente, leur état est maintenant "*yeux tapissés de pointes*".

L'expression *Faire les yeux [expression/qualité]* est correcte en français :

> - *Faire les yeux* doux à sa promise

Familièrement on dit à une personne étonnée :

> - Arrête de me *faire ces yeux* de merlans frits (très étonné).

L'utilisation de *faisait* (au lieu *étaient*) donne une intensité différente, un mouvement liée au moment. *[Najib](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/2181/najib-idrissi)* dans son commentaire propose l'équivalent *rendait*.

La phrase à prendre en compte :

> - ..., *je vis dans les yeux d’Andrée, **qu’il faisait pointus*** ,  ... , *passer un regard préoccupé*, ...

Si l'on change l'adjectif :

> - ..., *je vis dans les yeux d’Andrée, **qu’il faisait doux***,  ... , *passer un regard* 'léger', ...

... on ne peut plus replacer le verbe *étaient*, car il ne s'agit pas de la qualité des yeux, mais de  leur expression.

> - *... je vis dans les yeux d’Andrée, **qu’il faisait beau***,  ... , *passer un regard* 'adamantin', ...

... on ne pourrait pas dire *elle faisait beau*, ce n'est donc pas d'Andrée qu'il s'agit, mais de l'état changeant de ses yeux.

Il est possible de dire : « Madame, à vous voir (à voir votre regard), il fait beau (dans votre cœur)... »

On pourrait alors paraphraser :

> Andrée, pendant que je vous parle, il fait ***pointus*** (il y a des pointes), dans votre regard (vos yeux se sont durcis, aiguisés, ils sont incisifs)...

*Pointus*, allié au verbe *faire*, qualifie les yeux sans exprimer leur qualité biologique ou picturale ; il signe l'émotion naissante qui les traverse, les anime, il signale aussi un changement d'atmosphère.

M. Proust ayant déplacé les repères de la construction 'normale' d'une phrase offre une perspective différente, dans le registre de l'expression poétique.

Comment: Un vote négatif sans explication n'est pas dans les usages de ce site :)

Comment: Ce n'est pas la même construction que dans "faire les yeux doux", dans "faire les yeux doux" ou "faire ces yeux de merlans frits" le sujet aurait été Andrée et le pronom aurait été "elle". De nos jours on dirait plutôt "qu'il rendait pointus", il y a une différence entre "les yeux sont pointus" et "le regard rend les yeux pointus". J'ai l'impression que tu as l'air de faire un parallèle entre cette expression et l'expression "il fait beau", par exemple (ce n'est pas très clair), je pense que tu te trompes.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi -- J'ai essayé de clarifier ma réponse :)